# ¿Cómo introducir comandos en la consola de jmeter para cambiar el servidor proxy de este y poner el de mi compañia?

Tags: jmeter

necesito su ayuda,estoy trantando de aprender a hacer pruebas de estrés pero para ello el puerto del jmeter y del navegador no pueden entrar en conflicto, yo utilizo un servidor proxy empresarial y después de investigar me entere que había que usar la linea de comandos *jmeter -H -P  -u someusername -a someuserpassword -N localhost*, pero no logro que la consola me introduzca comandos, para ello vi que tenia que establecer unas variables de entorno en mi sistema pero después de tanto intentar aún no me funciona. Qué podría hacer?
Gracias de antemano y saludos.

Comment: "No logro que la consola me introduzca comandos". ¿Qué significa? ¿Te arroja error, no encuentras las consola, el teclado no funciona? ¿Cuales variables de entorno? ¿Usastes `set` o `export`?

Comment: En algunas páginas en las q investigue vi que le agregaban en las variables del sistema JMETER_HOME  y la variable la dirección donde tienes descomprimido el jmeter y la otra es crear una CLASSPATH y su variable %JMETER_HOME%\lib\ext\ApacheJMeter_core.jar; %JMETER_HOME%\lib\jorphan.jar;  pero ahora me cae duda si es este último se debe ajustar según la versión. Esto último era lo que vi para habilitar la consola

Comment: El problema es que el jmeter.bat inicialmente no permite introducir comandos por eso tienes que hacer lo que te comentaba arriba para habilitar la consola e introducir comandos pero no me funciona del todo, por eso necesito ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Bueno ya pude solucionar mi duda, de todas formas aqui voy a poner lo que hice por si alguna persona se encuentra en mi misma situación.
Para cambiar el servidor proxy del jmeter primeramente se debe configurar las variables de entorno tanto del JDK como del Jmeter.
La del JDK es poner en en Path de la variable del sistema la ruta donde se instaló este Ej: C:\Program File\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\bin.
Para el jmeter se debe crear en la variable del sistema JMETER_HOME y en la variable donde se descomprimio el jmeter y otra CLASSPATH % JMETER_HOME% / lib / ext / ApacheJMeter_core.jar;% JMETER_HOME% / lib / jorphan.jar.
Por último en Path de la variable del sistema tocas nuevo y pones %JMETER_HOME%\bin.
Ya ahi tienes configuradas las variables de entorno tanto del jdk como del jmeter. Luego abres la cmd e introduces el comando jmeter -v y presionas enter.
y luego pones jmeter -H 129.198.1.1 -P 8000 -u someusername -a someuserpassword -N localhost.